# How to write the equation for the input side of a JFET?

Tags: voltage, jfet, network, circuit-theory

I have been reading about the voltage gain of JFET, but I am unable to understand how to write the equation for the input side. Can somebody explain  the method to write the equation for the input side?

[image]

The text has provided \$V_i=V_{gs}+V_{Rs}\$ but I do not understand how this equation came up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I do not understand how this equation came up*

It's as easy as this: what ever voltage you have at the input with respect to 0 volts (\$V_i\$) must equal the voltage between gate and source (\$V_{GS}\$) plus the voltage between source and 0 volts (the voltage across \$R_S\$).

Answer (score 4):

> The text has provided Vi=Vgs+VRs but I do not understand how this equation came up.

This equation is a KVL equation. The left side is a voltage rise from 0V across RG. The right side is the sum of two voltage drops from gate to source and from the source back to 0V.